# repaint() erases previously drawn point

Tags: java, repaint

I am trying to plot the points clicked by the user on a JPanel. Am able to identify the coordinates, but when `repaint()` is called the previous points are overwritten.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;


/**
 *
 * @author emil
 */
public class GuiForTsp extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form GuiForTsp */
    class MousePanelA extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    public MousePanelA(){
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
        System.out.println("constructing MousePanelA");
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList xlist = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList ylist = new ArrayList();



    /*  public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("hi");
        }*/

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(x,y,5,5);
        System.out.println("filling rectangle");
        //repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse){
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked"); 
        count++;   
        x = mouse.getX();
        y = mouse.getY();
        xlist.add(x);
        ylist.add(y);
        System.out.println("x " + xlist);
        System.out.println("y " + ylist);

        System.out.println("x " + x);
        System.out.println("y " + y);
        //g.fillRect(x,y,5,5);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouse){ }   
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouse){ }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){ }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouse){ }
    }

    JButton jButton1;
    MousePanelA jPanel1;

    public GuiForTsp() {
    initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new MousePanelA();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30, 157, 164));


        jButton1.setText("Generate ");

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(67, 152, 46));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 287, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 283, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GuiForTsp().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     

    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Please tell me how to modify the program so that when clicking a new point it is displayed along with the previous points. I need to know if there is any simple means to do this other than storing the clicked points values and redrawing all of them each time a new point is clicked. It would be appreciable if you can provide the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should copy this Graphics into a Graphics2D.

Second, every repaint will draw all the screen again, you need to paint all the points every time on this method.

Those lists xList and yList has the previous points, why don't draw them?

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    for(int i = 0; i < xList.size(); i ++)
      g2d.fillRect(xList.get(i), yList.get(i), 5, 5);
    g2d.dispose();
    }
```

Also, consider using a List, not two List

Answer (score 0):

You should store the point coordinates in a collection (I suggest a LinkedList) and then you would parse that list (for each or any other loop you prefer) and paint each point again.

The thing is, you need to do this each time 'repaint()' is called, but (I think) it is called when you resize a window, for example, and you cannot overwrite this method. I know you have to place that snippet of code in a specific method, but I forgot which one (maybe in update(Graphics g) ?).

Hope this helps even if I didn't provide a perfect answer.

Comment: my bad, I didn't see that you had these xlist and ylist, you should just use them to re-draw the points.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) shows two ways to do this.